# Trouble with Port Forwarding and TWO physical webservers behind a router/firewall

Tags: web-server, port-forwarding

I have two (physical) web servers behind our SOHO router/modem. I know all about port forwarding and have done it many times.

**Is it possible to have both webservers handle public requests from people via port forwarding?** Of course, this is for incoming port 80/443. Not custom ports and no .. please don't suggest I use custom ports.

I know that i cannot have 2x port-forwarding rules for the same incoming ports. (that just makes no sense).

Currently, my port forwarding options are very simple -> incoming port (or range) <-> destination port.

First of all, I cannot move any of the sites from machine #2 to machine #1. But I was wondering if I could add FAKE sites to machine #1 .. which bounce the request to machine #2 ... and then the response goes out to the web?

FWIW -> the web servers are IIS7 on W2Kr2. SOHO modem/router is a [FRITZ! box](http://www.fritzbox.eu/index.php).

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using IIS on #1 as a reverse proxy should take care of your needs, if the namespaces are disjoint. See [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721138/iis-as-reverse-proxy) for some ways to implement a reverse proxy on IIS. It is possible you will need to do some rewriting as well, again depending on how your namespaces look.

Comment: That looks about right :) awesomesauce.

Comment: A problem with this is that if server #1 is down both servers are down.  How about using a router/firewall with the ability to do reverse proxying, such as PfSense with Proxy/mod_security?

Comment: If we're allowing for changes in architecture and aiming for less downtime, then moving to a colocation facility is likely going to be a bigger win than adding a more functional firewall. Hard to say what the right call is without knowing budget or uptime requirements.